# Slurm: some jobs stuck with status running but resources are available

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing, slurm

We encountered the problem that slurm jobs stuck with **JobState=RUNNING** but we have enough resources.

Slurm Job info

```
JobId=981862 JobName=original_3509604931_vs0_part0_6139c763ddf88b01ce4ab953_part0.py
   UserId=enc(1001) GroupId=enc(1001) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=9172 Nice=1000 Account=(null) QOS=normal
   JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:07:43 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2021-09-09T08:35:57 EligibleTime=2021-09-09T08:35:57
   AccrueTime=2021-09-09T08:35:57
   StartTime=2021-09-09T08:36:17 EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
   PreemptEligibleTime=2021-09-09T08:36:17 PreemptTime=None
   SuspendTime=2021-09-09T08:36:17 SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2021-09-09T08:36:17
   Partition=tran AllocNode:Sid=194.145.211.61:12930
   ReqNodeList=tf-125.biz ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=tf-125.biz
   BatchHost=tf-125.biz
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=1 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=1,node=1,billing=1
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=0 MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=encoding_cpu&mgg DelayBoot=00:00:00
   OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=original_3509604931_vs0_part0_6139c763ddf88b01ce4ab953_part0.py
   WorkDir=/home/enc/tm3
   Comment=TaskID:6139c763ddf88b01ce4ab953 
   StdErr=taskID-6139c763ddf88b01ce4ab953_slurm-error-981862.out
   StdIn=/dev/null
   StdOut=taskID-6139c763ddf88b01ce4ab953_slurm-output-981862.out
   Power=
```

slurm.conf

```
ClusterName=tmprod
ControlMachine=tf-1.biz
ControlAddr=tf-1.biz
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurmd
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/run/slurmd.pid
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
CacheGroups=0
ReturnToService=0
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/linear
FastSchedule=1
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/elasticsearch
JobCompLoc=http://tf-1.biz:9200
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageHost=tf-1.biz
AccountingStoragePort=6819
AccountingStorageLoc=slurm_acct_db

PreemptType=preempt/partition_prio
PreemptMode=SUSPEND,GANG

PartitionName=tran_1 Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
PartitionName=high_priority Nodes=ALL Default=NO PriorityTier=10 MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

PriorityType=priority/multifactor
PriorityWeightAge=10000
PriorityWeightJobSize=10000
PriorityWeightPartition=10000
PriorityWeightQOS=10000

RequeueExit=1
HealthCheckProgram=/usr/sbin/nhc
HealthCheckInterval=10
```

Only have an idea that the job has both **JobState=RUNNING** and **SuspendTime=2021-09-09T08:36:17** maybe it's not correct.

Currently, the job is stuck for 6 hours and there is no progress, while maximum it should work several minutes. Only **scontrol requeue job_id** helps, we wanted to avoid this manual manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this was the same case for you.

This situation just happened to me; And it turns out I wanted to get an interactive session and forgot to add the `--pty` option to the srun command.

Indeed I was running `srun -p mypartition bash` which gave me an apparently "stalled job" instead of `srun -p mypartition --pty bash` which gave me access to the allocated node.